# IE 10 Attach CSS

Tags: css, header, dynamics-crm, internet-explorer-10

I change my MS CRM 2011 header by adding a css file via Js and this works fine for IE9.

JS:

```
function ChangeColor()
{
var InternBool= document.getElementById('new_intern');
if(InternBool.value == 100000001)
{
var OrgUniqueName= Xrm.Page.context.getOrgUniqueName();
filename= OrgUniqueName + "//WebResources//new_Titlebar_Style";                 
attachCSS(filename);
}
}

function attachCSS(filename)
{       
var temp = $('head');
$("<link>")
  .appendTo($('head'))
  .attr({type : 'text/css', rel : 'stylesheet'})
  .attr('href', filename);
}
```

CSS:

```
.ms-crm-Form-HeaderContainer{ 
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffB3CAEC, endColorstr=#fff6f8faE); 
}
```

I tried several ways with appending children, links etc., but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

IE10 supports [CSS3 gradients](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/) and drops support for the `DX*` transforms. Instead you can use standard CSS3 to do it. A site like [the ultimate CSS gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) can help generate you the cross-browser CSS that you require (including all vendor prefixes), but I'm pretty sure this is what you're after:

```
.ms-crm-Form-HeaderContainer {
background: #2989d8; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #2989d8 0%, #ffb3ca 0%, #fff6f8 100%, #207cca 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2989d8), color-stop(0%,#ffb3ca), color-stop(100%,#fff6f8), color-stop(100%,#207cca)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #2989d8 0%,#ffb3ca 0%,#fff6f8 100%,#207cca 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #2989d8 0%,#ffb3ca 0%,#fff6f8 100%,#207cca 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #2989d8 0%,#ffb3ca 0%,#fff6f8 100%,#207cca 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #2989d8 0%,#ffb3ca 0%,#fff6f8 100%,#207cca 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2989d8', endColorstr='#207cca',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Just substitute the appropriate start/end colours

Comment: Thank you very much!! I spend hours on this issue and it works with a few clicks now.